# Can XSLT detect the version of the Saxon engine being used?

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have a third party application that is using the Saxon XSLT transformation engine. Let's call it Application X. Depending on the version Application X, the Saxon version can differ.

I have an XSLT stylesheet in Application X that invokes a custom .NET library. From what we have been able to determine, Saxon changed the way it allows you to invoke a .NET library in XSLT between Saxon versions 9.9 and 10.

I'm looking to see if there is an extension function or other logic I could use in my XSL to detect the version of Saxon so I can have my template auto-adjust its logic based on the Saxon version.

I don't want the XSL version. I need the version of Saxon.

Does anyone know if there's an XSL or Saxon XSLT extension function that will return the Saxon version?

I looked in the Saxon 10 documentation and did not see a version function in their extension functions for 9.9 or 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `system-property('xsl:product-version')`.

Comment: Indeed. Typical output will be something like "EE 10.6".